# Wordpress query grouped by taxonomy sub terms

Tags: wordpress

In my Query, I'm having trouble displaying the data the way I want.
I have a custom post type with categories (custom taxonomy) that have child categories. For example:

Adults

- sports
- music

Teens

- games
- music

I have a page for each parent category (Adults, Children, etc.) in which I want to list the posts grouped by child category. For example, in the Adults page, I will have all the posts of the Adults category. These posts will be grouped  by child category (sports, music, etc). For example:

Adults page (only displays posts in the Adult category)

Sports

- post 1
- post 2

Music

- post 3
- post 4

Teens page (only displays posts in the Teens category)

Games

- post 5
- post 6

Music

- post 7
- post 8

I managed to get my query to work, but it prints out all the posts regardless of categories:

Adults (page)

Adults (category - should not be displayed)

- post 1
- post 2
- post 3
- post 4

Sports

- post 1
- post 2

Music

- post 3
- post 4

Teens (from here to the end - should not be displayed in Adults page)

- post 5
- post 6
- post 7
- post 8

Games

- post 5
- post 6

Music

- post 7
- post 8

It seems the taxonomy terms are not added correctly. Here is my query so far:

```
        <?php
    /**
    *
    * Loop through some custom post types and group them by taxonomy term,
    * outputting the taxonomy term names before the set of posts
    *
    */

    // get all of the custom taxonomy terms
    $taxonomy = 'groupe';
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'term' => 'adultes',
    );
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);

    // if there are some taxonomy terms, loop through each one and get the posts in that term
    if($taxonomy_terms) {
        foreach($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'activite',
                "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

          <!-- output the taxonomy name for the current term -->
                <h2><?php echo $taxonomy_term->name; ?></h2>

                <div class="cpts-wrap">

          <!-- loop over the posts -->
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div><!-- .cpts-wrap -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // so nothin' weird happens to other loops
            endif;

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: sorry I misread your question I have deleted the awnser

Comment: I read it again but I'm not sure on the expected output can you please clarify what the full output should be ?

Comment: HI Jasper, thanks for taking some time to look at it. 
You're right, it's not very clear. I edited my question to detail it better

Answer (score 0):

Given, this is the archive page for the given taxonomy the below code should work

```
<?php
    /**
    *
    * Loop through some custom post types and group them by taxonomy term,
    * outputting the taxonomy term names before the set of posts
    *
    */

    // Get the current queried Taxonomy Object
    $current = get_queried_object();
        
    // get all of the custom taxonomy terms
    $taxonomy = 'groupe';
    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'id',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'term' => 'adultes',
        'parent'=>$current->term_id,
    );
    $taxonomy_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, $args);

    // if there are some taxonomy terms, loop through each one and get the posts in that term
    if($taxonomy_terms) {
        foreach($taxonomy_terms as $taxonomy_term) {

            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'activite',
                "$taxonomy" => $taxonomy_term->slug,
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
            );

            $query = new WP_Query( $args );

            if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>

          <!-- output the taxonomy name for the current term -->
                <h2><?php echo $taxonomy_term->name; ?></h2>

                <div class="cpts-wrap">

          <!-- loop over the posts -->
                <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
                    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                </div><!-- .cpts-wrap -->

            <?php wp_reset_postdata(); // so nothin' weird happens to other loops
            endif;

        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late response.
Turns out i was completeley wrong.
Since I'm listing custom post types and not pages. All I have to do is create a taxonomy template (and not a page template). That takes care of the first taxonomy level. All that is left is group activities by sub categories.

Here's my code

```
        <?php

    $this_term = get_queried_object();
    $args = array(
        'parent' => $this_term->term_id,
        'orderby' => 'slug',
        'hide_empty' => true
    );
    $child_terms = get_terms( $this_term->taxonomy, $args );

    if(!empty($child_terms)) {
        foreach ($child_terms as $term) {

            // List the child topic
            echo '<div class="bloc-activite">';
            echo '<h2>' . $term->name . '</h2>';
            echo '<div class="section-activite">';
            // Get posts from that child topic
            $query = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'activite',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => 'ASC',

                'tax_query' => array(
                    'relation' => 'AND',
                    array(
                        'taxonomy' => $this_term->taxonomy,
                        'field'    => 'slug',
                        'terms'    => array( $term->slug ),
                    )
                )
            ) );

            // List the posts
            if($query->have_posts()) {
                while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post(); ?>

            // insert template part or code below
                <?php get_template_part(  'partials/content', "activite" );  ?>

                <?php
            endwhile;
        }
        echo "</div></div>";


    } //end foreach
}
else  {
    echo '<p class="no-content">Message if no activities.</p>';
}
?>
```